# Static site generator with preview server and built-in automatic live reload

Tags: linux, open-source, static-site-generator

I’m looking for a **static site generator** that is **FLOSS** and runs natively on **GNU/Linux**.

The tool **must not**:

- require a separate local server (e.g., I don’t want to run an Apache with PHP to be able to use it)
- assume that I want to build a blog and make other site types hard to build

The tool **must**:

- come with a local **test server** with **live reload** (so I can see template/content changes live in the browser without having to reload the page)

  - the live reload feature must be built-in and work automatically, so no installation of a plugin or having to manually insert JavaScript to the pages
- **export** the generated site into *one* folder which contains nothing else (so I can copy-paste its content without having to omit/add any files)
- allow generating other **formats** than HTML (e.g., XML, plain text, …)
- leave full control over the output **markup** to me (e.g., it must not make assumptions like adding a DOCTYPE or generating feed markup, unless I can easily overwrite it)

Comment: I’m currently examining [Hugo](http://hugo.spf13.com/) which *might* be a match. If someone knows Hugo well and is sure about the mentioned requirements (I’m unsure about my last two points), feel free to add it as answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Hugo, http://gohugo.io/

It does not require a separate server, and there are many examples of non-blog layouts.

- Test server and livereload: **Yes**.

  The livereload also distinguishes between image/CSS changes and content changes - image/CSS changes triggers a "soft reload" in the browser (the "soft reload" require the latest 0.13 version). Works out of the box, no config needed.
- Export to folder that can be copy-pasted to server: **Yes**.
- Other formats: **Kind of**.

  It currently generates HTML and (optional) XML. There is an open request on GitHub that wants JSON. But the output document types are currently hard wired.
- Full control of the markup: **Yes**.

  All the built-in templates can be overridden.